# Sum of Ideals of the Same Type

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I have two questions:

1) Is a finite sum of idempotent ideals of a ring $R$ idempotent?

2) Is *any* sum of nil ideals of a ring $R$ nil?

As far as I know, a finite sum of  nil ideals of a commutative ring $R$ is nil too by Koethe conjecture which is true for such rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) Every element which belongs to a sum of ideals belongs to a finite sum of them.

Answer (score 1):

1) If $I$ and $J$ are idempotent ideals of $R$ then we have:

$(I+J)^2=I^2+IJ+JI+J^2=I+J$, since $IJ⊆I=I^2$ and also, $JI⊆J=J^2$. The general result would follow by induction.

Comment: @user26857 I think that one could well generalize my solution to an arbitrary sum of idempotent ideals. In fact, if $S=\sum _t I_t$ where $t$ runs in an arbitrary index set so that $I_t$'s are idempotent ideals then $S^2=\sum_t {I_t}^2+\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is a sum each of whose summands is an ideal contained in some $I_t$. Hence, $S^2=\sum_t I_t+\sigma=S$.